# hCaptcha : CORS error even if I've added a local DN in my Ubuntu host file

Tags: php, laravel, cors, captcha

## Summary

1. Context
2. The problem

   1. Expected behavior
   2. Actual behavior
3. What I've tried
4. Clues to help you to help me
5. Final question

---

## Context

I'm trying to locally test on Chromium hCaptcha, set on a form. My Laravel 8 site is running thanks to `php artisan serve --host=myhost`.

## The problem

### Expected behavior

I open the form page, hCaptcha shows no error and actually shows the captcha.

### Actual behavior

- **I go to the form page** which contains the hCaptcha widget. (I don't click on the button "Send Form": I actually *just* go to the form page). The hCaptcha widget doesn't show the captcha but instead shows this error message:

  > Limited rate or network error. Please retry.
- **I open the Chromium console.**

  - **In the network tab:** I can see this error request (its status = `CORS error`): `https://hcaptcha.com/checksiteconfig?host=myhost&sitekey=XYZ&sc=1&swa=1` (with `Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`). Its `OPTIONS` `POST` request's status is `200`;
  - **In the console tab:**

  > Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://hcaptcha.com/checksiteconfig?host=myhost&sitekey=XYZ&sc=1&swa=1' from origin 'https://newassets.hcaptcha.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

  > hcaptcha-checkbox.js:1 GET https://hcaptcha.com/checksiteconfig?host=myhost&sitekey=XYZ&sc=1&swa=1 net::ERR_FAILED

## What I've tried

I've followed the hCaptcha documentation: https://docs.hcaptcha.com/#local-development. Note that I actually followed this doc which is about the vanilla hCaptcha (*i.e.:* I don't use any Laravel/Blade's implementation of hCaptcha). Thus:

1. Ive typed `cat /etc/host`:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
> 127.0.1.1 myhost

2. I run my PHP server that serves my Laravel site with: `php artisan serve --host=myhost`
3. I open my Laravel site with this URL: http://myhost:8000/contact

## Clues to help you to help me

I've seen that the hCaptcha docs speak about ***127.0.0.1*** as you can read it: `127.0.0.1 test.mydomain.com`. In my own Ubuntu `etc/host` I see: `127.0.1.1 myhost` myhost`(127.0.***1***.1).`myhost`is actually the host I use so I actually use`127.0.1.1`instead of`127.0.0.1`.

So: perhaps the hCaptcha client must be configured to use 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1?

## Final question

What could I do to reach the expected behavior from the actual one?

Comment: I'm not familiar with hCaptcha but may similar services require you to register the domains that you will  be using to access the service. For CORS purposes the domain must include protocol and port so in your case that would be `http://myhost:8000`

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for your help. I've found a solution to my problem, see the answer I've posted. Note that I don't understand why it works. It's a purely random-thought fix.

Answer (score 1):

From the [hCaptcha documentation](https://docs.hcaptcha.com/#local-development):

> Modern browsers have strict CORS and CORB rules, so opening a
> `file://URI` that loads hCaptcha will not work. Loading hCaptcha from
> `http://localhost/` will encounter the same issue on some browsers. The
> hCaptcha API also prohibits `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` as supplied
> hostnames.
>
> The simplest way to circumvent these issues is to add a hosts entry.
> For example:
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 test.mydomain.com
> ```
>
> Place this in `/etc/hosts` on Linux, `/private/etc/hosts` on Mac OS X, or
> `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows.
>
> You can then access your local server via http://test.mydomain.com,
> and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Read the OP, that's what I did ;-)

Comment: True, but my answer answers your question "I don't know why it works now. If someone knowing well hCaptcha could explain why it fixed my problem it would be pretty cool :-) ." and includes documentation for other users to solve a similar problem too.

Comment: The part "What I've tried" was written before I find a solution and corresponds exactly to what you wrote in your answer; the solution I've found is based on it BUT the only difference is: `.2.` in the IP and I don't know why it fixed the issue. The answer I wait for the question you quoted above is lwould likely be a network answer (I think). That's why I can't accept your answer. I will upvote it if you want ;-). Edit: I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Problem was solved by adding this entry in `/etc/host` (Ubuntu):

`127.0.2.1 myhost.local`

Of course now I run my site with:

`php artisan serve --host=myhost.local`

I didn't change anything else. I don't know why it works now. If someone knowing well hCaptcha could explain why it fixed my problem it would be pretty cool :-) .

Edit:

NB: please read the part "What I've tried" in the OP (which is anterior to this answer). The unique difference seems: ".2." in the IP. The type of comment to this answer that would explain why this answer works would be rather "network" than "programming", I think.